# Making timestamp field available in kibana via elasticsearch with kafka

Tags: kibana, avro, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

How do I allow kibana to use my timestamp field as @timestamp when adding data via Kafka elasticsearch connector?

I am defining my avro schema like so

```
    public static String userSchema =  "{\"type\":\"record\"," +
                                         "\"name\":\"myrecord\"," +
                                         "\"fields\":[" +
                                         "{\"name\":\"wSrcTime\",\"type\":[\"string\", \"null\"],\"default\":\"null\"}," +
                                         "{\"name\":\"wTradePrice\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"float\"],\"default\":null}," +
                                         "{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}}" +
                                         "]}";
```

and use this to populate the field

```
avroRecord.put("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I see the data kafka-avro-console-consumer as follows:

```
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:40.127"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672840137}
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:41.062"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672841072}
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:41.062"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672841073}
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:41.064"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672841075}
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:41.065"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672841076}
{"wSrcTime":{"string":"2019-08-01 15:20:41.410"},"wTradePrice":null,"timestamp":1564672841420}
```

And see the data added to kibana index as

```
timestamp: number
wTradePrice: number
wSrcTime: string
```

Is there a recommended way of making timestamp @timestamp so I can use it on an axis?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ingest-pipeline on elasticsearch so you can rename the timestamp field to @timestamp before indexing the documents.

Create the pipeline on the elastic:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/rename_timestamp
{
  "rename": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "target_field": "@timestamp"
  }
}
```

And you should provide the pipeline name when indexing the new documents into database like

```
PUT /es-index/_doc?pipeline=rename_timestamp
{
  "timestamp": "value"
  ...
}
```